# First Visible Row in Codenameone

Tags: row, codenameone

I tried this code to get the first visible row in a scrolling Table inside a BorderLayout.CENTER, but it didn't work, seems the points returned do not reflect the visible cells, unless I am missing a sort of calculation,

thank you for your insights,

```
@Override
protected void onScrollY(int scrollY) {
    super.onScrollY(scrollY); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    
    Component c=getComponentAt(50, scrollY);
    if (c instanceof Table){
        System.err.println("table "+getWidth()+" "+getHeight()+" s "+scrollY);
        return;
    }
    Button b=(Button) c;

    System.err.println("c: "+b.getText());
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getComponentAt(x,y)` takes absolute (screen) coordinates.  The `scrollY` value is a relative coordinate in that container.

So what you want is something like:

```
Component c = getComponentAt(getAbsoluteX()+50, getAbsoluteY() + scrollY)
```

Also worth nothing that `getComponentAt(x,y)` will only return components that are focusable or have been set to grab pointer events.  If you just want to find the first paintable immediate child of this container, and you're using a BoxLayout.Y_AXIS layout, then you might be better to just iterate through the children until you find one where y is at least the scrollY.

e.g.

```
Component c = null;
for (Component child : this) {
    if (child.getY() + child.getHeight() > scrollY) {
        c = child;
        break;
    }
}
....
```